# Failed to download or parse release-index.json with error:

Tags: azure-devops

My Azure Devops build has started failing with the following message in the log

```
Starting: Use .NET Core sdk
==============================================================================
Task         : Use .NET Core
Description  : Acquires a specific version of the .NET Core SDK from the internet or the local cache and adds it to the PATH. Use this task to change the version of .NET Core used in subsequent tasks. Additionally provides proxy support.
Version      : 2.165.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/AA4xgy0
==============================================================================
Tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 3.x.
##[error]Failed to download or parse release-index.json with error: {}
Finishing: Use .NET Core sdk
```

The YAML contains

```
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: 3.x
```

the image is windows-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the pipeline again some time later and it worked.
I had enabled diagnostics. Not sure if that helped.

Comment: I had same issue, maybe some agents are not behaving the same way behind the scene

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue, github was down.

After github came back up, this step worked in the pipeline.

Also relevant:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10969